# Web scraping (Regex)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to do some scraping on a web page with nodejs.

I get the request body as HTML.

in the HTML u have this piece of code:

```
<h2>JavaScript required</h2>
<p>The Low Fare Finder requires JavaScript in order to work. Please use a browser that supports JavaScript, and mke sure that it is enabled.</p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {

    new LowFareFinder.LowFareFinder({
        container: '#lff-container',
        ABCD: [{"code":"jhkj","name":"hjk","country":"gjhgj","imageUrl":"hgkjf/GRZ.png","nearby":["ghj","jhg","jh","jg"]
        },
        languageCode: 'en',
        pricesAvailable: true
    });
        })();
```

I need the json string that starts after the "ABCD".

What would be the best way of doing it?

Thanks
Avi

Comment: "the json string that starts after the "ABCD"" —That is neither JSON nor is it a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = `<h2>JavaScript required</h2>
<p>The Low Fare Finder requires JavaScript in order to work. Please use a browser that supports JavaScript, and mke sure that it is enabled.</p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {

    new LowFareFinder.LowFareFinder({
        container: '#lff-container',
        ABCD: [{"code":"jhkj","name":"hjk","country":"gjhgj","imageUrl":"hgkjf/GRZ.png","nearby":["ghj","jhg","jh","jg"]
        },
        languageCode: 'en',
        pricesAvailable: true
    });
        })();`
        
let foo = str.match(/ABCD:.*?\n/gm)        
console.log(foo);
```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for text after **ABCD:** excluding the space using regex:

```js
const regex = /(?<=ABCD:\s).*/mg;
const str = `<p>The Low Fare Finder requires JavaScript in order to work. Please use a browser that supports JavaScript, and mke sure that it is enabled.</p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {

new LowFareFinder.LowFareFinder({
    container: '#lff-container',
    ABCD: [{"code":"jhkj","name":"hjk","country":"gjhgj","imageUrl":"hgkjf/GRZ.png","nearby":["ghj","jhg","jh","jg"]
    },
    languageCode: 'en',
    pricesAvailable: true
});
    })();\``;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(match);
  });
}
```